# Positioning of an html element over a javascript one

Tags: javascript, html, z-index, positioning

this is the website I'm working on: http://labbrini.netsons.org and on its left side I have a div (#puntate) that should be on top of the javascript of the big lips logo (#logo) that shows up over everything. Of course I need the links of #puntate being clickable even when logo shows over it. z-index doesn't works for this. Can somebody help me with this positioning?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: You should mention your problem html and css code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While inspecting your code in my browser, I saw that you were using `px` for `z-index`.

**Dont give any units for `z-index`**

In your CSS, replace,

```
z-index: 900px;
```

with

```
z-index: 900;
```

As, stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants.

And, order doesnt have a unit. Thus no need for any units. Any element with a higher z-index will be on top of other elements.

Comment: Oh thank you! That was my very big mistake. Now it works but I needed to create another div

Comment: Great..:) glad that it helped. But you could have marked the answer as accepted as the answer solves the exact problem.

Comment: Done now. Sorry, I'm new here and you can understand me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. The value to the z-index was my stupid mistake. But I needed to tinker a little bit more in order to get what I wanted. I created another div #left2

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="left2"><div id="puntate"><ahref="http://labbrini.netsons.org/Labbrinip1"> 
Labbrini p.1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a><br/> 
</div></div>
```

so that my div in question (#puntate) belongs to the new one and I set the background-color to transparent in order to see below the old one with the color transition:

```
#left2 {
background-color : transparent;
position:fixed;
display: table;
z-index:1000;
width:50%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

and of course the z-index of #puntate is set to an higher value than #logo

I'm sorry for not having posted previously the code.